# Duplicated linked item found in the project xxxx bundleconfig.json

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package, visual-studio-2017

I am installing a NuGet Package built from an ASP.NET Core 1.1 class library (embedded view components) into my ASP.NET Core 1.1 web application.

Today the application does not want to load in the project in VS.2017 and giving me this error on the web application project (where I included the NUPKG):

```
Duplicate linked item found in the project "C:\Users\NAME\.nuget\packages\mypackagetitle\0.0.3\contentFiles\any\netcoreapp1.1\bundleconfig.json
```

I am puzzled... When I think of it, I do NOT want a bundleconfig.json to be packaged into the NUGET, I only want it to be used for bundlying and minifying the class library prior to building the NUPKG but I do NOT want it included in the NUPKG. I am beginning to think the problem is that because when I look in that folder mentioned above I see bundleconfig.json as part of the included package in both the content\ and contentFiles\ but should be in none of them.